# Google image search api. Bad request

Tags: json, ajax, request, google-search-api, google-image-search

I'm using Google CustomSearch API v1 for image search but I have a problem with my JSON request.

When I filled out the search.cse.list ([here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list)) I got the JSON request like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=test&cref=AIzaSyAreDhTh3IqaGPqC44t08sQF_qbSGzzA7Q&cx=010855067127206535986%3Aqdh_vhglb4u&fileType=jpg&filter=1&imgSize=medium&imgType=news&num=4&searchType=image&start=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And the response of this request:

```
{
 "kind": "customsearch#search",
 "url": {
  "type": "application/json",
  "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
 },
 "queries": {
  ...
 },
 "context": {
  ...
 },
 "searchInformation": {
  ...
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "free student testing cartoons | Home > Clipart > Cartoons ...",
   "htmlTitle": "free student <b>testing</b> cartoons | Home &gt; Clipart &gt; Cartoons <b>...</b>",
   "link": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/30/0c/a5/300ca57d460ab787202e36bdf0364e57.jpg",
   "displayLink": "www.pinterest.com",
   "snippet": "free student testing cartoons",
   "htmlSnippet": "free student <b>testing</b> cartoons",
   "mime": "image/jpeg",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "https://www.pinterest.com/pin/568157309212095926/",
    "height": 213,
    "width": 236,
    "byteSize": 14426,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ-JefdKWd1WZkuesaq01zldYRW2JmYd_z0cW0SF9OEXFMVr6M8XZO4kg",
    "thumbnailHeight": 98,
    "thumbnailWidth": 109
   }
  },
```

But when I tried to use this request at the browser bar I got an error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
 }
}
```

I guess that I should use Ajax call, but I dont know how can I do it, because I am beginner.

I also made an API Key, "cx" and have enabled CustomSearch API at my console.developer account.

So the question is: How can I get values from this JSON request and then operate with them if I even cant get values in my browser? I want to get an image-link from this request.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: The problem here seems to be with your setup, not with how you work with the JSON response.

Comment: Setup of what? I just thought that i have a trouble with my api_key... But i'm not sure.

Comment: Very possibly, I would gues that you had to specific a domain to make the request from?   so you'll need to do it with Ajax from that domain firstly, secondly, confirm that your google dashbaord settings are correct.  I would highly reccommend a) using a tool like postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en  to check your queries, and once they're working from there then integrate them into your script.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Image Search API was deprecated in 2011, and has finally, now, been switched off :(  You'll have to find something else to use, sorry :(